# SP 2010 - Setting value in newform from a lookup list

Tags: 2010, newform

I have two lists we'll call List A and List B.  List B is a lookup list for List A.  List B has two columns.  Column 1 is the lookup value.  Column 2 is some additional information.

What I'd like to make happen is this. In the Newform for List A, when the lookup value is selected from List B/Column 1, I'd like to populate a different field in the Newform with the value from List B/Column 2.

This would need to happen real-time, so a workflow won't cut it.  I'm working with Sharepoint Designer 2010, no Infopath.  I'm using Javascript in the form already, so that's a possible avenue.

Answer (score 0):

One relatively quick way to do it would be to use the SPServices JavaScript library and use its SPDisplayRelatedInfo function. It normally is used to display other fields from a lookup, but you can use CSS to hide what it would have normally displayed (col 2 from list B in your example) and use its completefunc callback to populate your other form field with that value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to achieve something like this -->

Question: 
2  dropdowns

country which has following values-

1)India

2)US

3)UK

and states list which has-

1)Pune

2)Goa

3)Manhattan

4)Chicago

5)Coventry

6)Leeds

now when i click on India it should only display Goa and Pune (for US Manhattan and Chicago and for UK Leeds and Coventry)

*****************************Reference Code Start******************************

First create a list called country and add item to Tilte(India,US,UK)

Title

---

India
US
UK

Create a list called State and create a lookup field called Country. Add item to  Country and Title.
Country - Title

---

India - Pune
India - Goa
US - Manhattan
US - Chicago like this.

put this code your SharePoint Designer Page. It will work.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "YourListName",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Country",
        childColumn: "State",
        debug: true
    })
})

}

*****************************Reference Code End******************************

Thanks.

Reference : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f0dc9108-dea2-4ac8-9553-00206b028d92/working-cascading-drop-down-using-javascript-in-share-point-2013-?forum=sharepointgeneral